# How to show $\nabla_a\nabla_c R_{ad}-\nabla_c \nabla _a R_{ad}=-R_{cade} R_{ae}-R_{ce} R _{de}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

$\nabla$ is Riemann connection and $R_{ij}=g^{kl}R_{ikjl}$.

How to show $\nabla_a\nabla_c R_{ad}-\nabla_c \nabla _a R_{ad}=-R_{cade} R_{ae}-R_{ce} R _{de}$ ?

Or generate commutator of generate tensor ?

Comment: are you using Einstein convention? Index a 2 times in a lower position seems fishy.

Comment: @user26977   Yes, in Riemann geometry, Einstein convention is common

Comment: Then your expression should be corrected. You must not have any index appearing twice in the same position in one term. For example $R_{ce} R_{de}$ should be replaced by $R_c^e R_{de}$ or $R_{ce}R_d^e$. Which one is it? You have the same problem in all other terms with indices $a$ and $e$.

Comment: @user26977  no, it should be $R_{ce}R_{de}$ sum over $e$.

Comment: Then you cannot use Einstein convention, since your expression is meaningless

Comment: @user26977  but it is done in 230 page of http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947